# If there are more than 12 column in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I am displaying data in gridview,that has 12 column.When I displaying it ,it is going beyound the page.I am writing in content page.I can't modify master page.

Comment: You are going to have to give us at least some code or html!
Other than that the only suggestion is apply some style to it.. but without knowing exactly what you are doing it's very difficult!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the gridview in a div, and allow the div to have horizontal (and vertical if you need) scrolling.

```
<div style="background-position: center; text-align: center; 
  width: 400px; overflow: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"
  align="center">
<!-- your gridview here -->
</div>
```

Comment: See Shark,with this I am able to do scroll bar to grid,but my grid is going outside of the page.That I don't want that and one more can  I make div  to visible =false.I want to show scroll bar,then there only grid.